# How can i save more than one edit text boxes

Tags: java, android

Hello i have a timetable app and want to save the lessons that are imputed. There are 5 lessons on each day so 5 edit text boxes. But i want to enter different text in each one and save them for when i next go on the app. At the moment i have the code below but when i enter the text in editBox2 it also chnages the text editBox1 to whatever it says in editBox1. How can i solve this. Any help would be much appreicated. P.s i am a beginner.

Comment: I'll try that in a bit and we if it works, thanks greg-449

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem is here- `editor.putString("text", editBox.getText().toString());` and `editor.putString("text", editBox1.getText().toString());`

you are using the same 'text' key for both values.

then when you load it here - `String restoredText = prefs.getString("text", null);` it will be whatever you set it to last

and  then here - `editBox.setText(restoredText, TextView.BufferType.EDITABLE);
         editBox1.setText(restoredText, TextView.BufferType.EDITABLE);`
you fill both edit text boxes with this value.

change 'text' to 'text1' and 'text2' and then load those for each editBox.

hope this helps

Comment: I will try that too as well as greg-442 one :)

Comment: I decied to try yours first and with some other filleing around i made it work! Now you've told me it seems so obvious! i've been looking all over online and now worked it out! I thank you so much and anyone else who has helped me. Thanks

Comment: you are very welcome. don't forget to mark the correct answer so people can reference this in the future

Comment: I have now got this problem, look at orginal post... When i enter text in all 5 boxes only the first ones saves. Look at code in OP.

Comment: Don't worry hahah i got it to work hahah. Thanks for the other help again though.

Answer (score -1):

You can [save the data to a database](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/databases.html) and retrieve when you reopen the app

Comment: Sorry what do you mean? Do you mean that I save edit box1's data in a databse1 and then save edit box2's data in a database2. Then retrieve it. How would I do that.